# How can I change default Couchbase item size?

Tags: c#, couchbase, membase, enyim

I am using the .NET Couchbase Client API that includes Enyim.Caching.  I have a DataTable that is approximately 55 megs and it is not getting cached.  I understand that there is a "soft" max for the item size of 20 megs.

How can I change the default max item size in order to cache this object?

Comment: Status code 3 is E2BIG which you should not be getting if the object is less than 20MB. Can you double check the size and also post your code?

Comment: Edited question.  I put the decimal in the wrong place.  It's 55 megs instead of 5.5 megs for the item.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per MikeW from the Couchbase forum post [here](http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/change-maximum-item-size):

> This requires modifying a constant in the source code and building Couchbase yourself.

It seems as if there isn't a way around it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Memcached bucket or Couchbase bucket?  If you're using a Memcached bucket then you're likely hitting the 1MB limit.  A quick sample program:

```
var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration();
config.Urls.Add(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default"));
config.Bucket = "memcached";
config.BucketPassword = "qwerty";
var client = new CouchbaseClient(config);

var size = 1000000;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { sb.Append("z"); };
var data = sb.ToString();
var result = client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "foo", data);
Console.WriteLine(data.Length + ": " + result);
```

When the `size` variable is set to 1000000, `result` is true.  When `size` is set to just over a MB, say 1100000, then `result` will be false.  If you instead use a Couchbase bucket, you can set `size` to 20000000 and the `result` will be true.  However, setting `size` to 21000000 will cause the `Store` operation to fail.

If you're not using a Memcached bucket, please let me know...  Also, note that I'm using the .NET 1.0 client with 1.8 server for this sample.

-- John

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I actually changed the question since I originally miscounted the bytes.  I was attempting to store 55 megs and not 5.5 megs, which changed my problem.  I am using Couchbase v1.8 with the .NET Couchbase Client API, though.

Comment: Is there any way around the 1MB limit when using a Memcached bucket?