# where to set VALUE SIZE to more than 20MB in couchbase source code?

Tags: membase, couchbase

This question was asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933666/how-can-i-change-default-couchbase-item-size)

But didn't mention in which file and what constant, we need to change this limit.

I found few checks in test code but not in source code

ep-engine/ep_testsuite.cc:

```
rv = h1->allocate(h, NULL, &it, "key", 3, 20 * 1024 * 1024, 0, 0);
memcachetest/main.c:    if (size > 1024 * 1024 *20) {
```

Can you please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

It's hardcoded in the configuration.json file in the ep-engine project under the variable name max_item_size. You could modify it here and build the project or you can also specify a different value on the command line when starting memcached. For example if you just wanted to run the our memcached without all of the cluster management stuff you can run:

./memcached -E (path to ep-engine lib 'ep.so') -e max_item_size=your_size

Comment: Just now, I found in ep_engine.cc 
>> maxItemSize(20*1024*1024). Thanks a lot Mike. I will get back to you If I have any more issues.